# MySQL delete con count de dos tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas una llamada acciones y otra respuestas, 
la tabla acciones tiene un id que es un num. entero y la tabla de respuestas tiene un campo llamado id_respuestas que también es un entero, necesito saber como podría hacer un delete a acciones teniendo que hacer un count al id_respuestas, si es cero si se podría eliminar. Tengo que hacerlo con el count porque el id_respuestas se puede repetir, ya que las respuestas se pueden usar en varias acciones.
Apenas llevó un select pero está mal, ya que me sale error:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (  
SELECT DISTINCT respuestas.id  FROM respuestas JOIN acciones ON acciones.id_respuesta)
```

Comment: No logro entender cual es la tabla principal en la relación.  Podrías indicar cómo sería la relación entre estas dos tablas?

Comment: ¿La tabla respuestas tiene como foránea la llave id de la tabla acciones? Pues allí debes empezar a armar la consulta porque el JOIN no está bien.

Comment: si tiene como llave fóranea

Comment: la tabla principal es la de acciones, que tiene un id y en la de respuesta sale esa id_respuestas y en ese campo se obtiene del id de acciones

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tus comentarios sería algo como esto:

```
DELETE FROM respuestas 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT id_respuesta 
    FROM preg_respuestas 
) preguntas_respuestas ON preguntas_respuestas.id_respuesta= respuestas.id 
WHERE preguntas_respuestas IS NULL 
    AND respuestas.id = 5454
```

La subconsulta

```
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT id_respuesta 
        FROM preg_respuestas 
)
```

devuelve todos los id de respuestas que estén relacionados con alguna pregunta.

`ON preguntas_respuestas.id_respuesta= respuestas.id` relaciona la tabla de respuestas con la subconsulta de respuestas asociadas a preguntas.

`WHERE preguntas_respuestas IS NULL` le dice que tenga en cuenta sólo los registros donde no encuentre el id de respuesta en la subconsulta de respuestas asociadas a preguntas, es decir las respuestas que no sean parte de una pregunta.

`AND respuestas.id = 5454`  para eliminar sólo una respuesta.  En ese caso se reemplazaría el 5454 por el id de la respuesta que se pretende eliminar.

Comment: Lo importante para poder eliminar no es si una respuesta se repite o no en varias acciones, lo importante es saber si la acción tiene algún registro en la tabla de respuestas.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias intente adaptar el query pero me marca error, te puedo dejar el link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311050/mysql-delete-tablas

Comment: Puedes dejar aquí la consulta que adaptaste y el error que te arroja?

Comment: DELETE FROM respuestas
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM respuestas
) preguntas_respuestas ON preguntas_respuestas.id_respuesta= respuestas.id
WHERE preguntas_respuestas IS NULL
  AND respuestas.id = 5454 y el error que me salía era cerca del left join

Comment: Cuál de las dos es la tabla de la que quieres borrar registros?

Comment: De la de respuestas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101443/discussion-between-johan-donado-b-and-ricardo).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo de tu pregunta y los comentarios que has hecho es que buscas eliminar las `respuestas` que no tengan `preg_respuestas` relacionadas. Si es esto, es un patrón que se conoce como anti join, por ejemplo para consultar los casos:

```
SELECT id
       FROM respuestas
       WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_respuesta FROM preg_respuestas)
```

Y para eliminar:

```
DELETE respuestas
      WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_respuesta FROM preg_respuestas)
```