# mysql delete tablas

Tags: php, mysql

Esta es mi tabla de respuestas:

[image: TABLA DE RESPUESTAS]

Y esta mi tabla preg_respuestas:

[image: tabla de preg_respuestas]

Necesito saber cómo puedo hacer un delete ya que una respuesta puede ser usada varias veces en la tabla de preg_respuestas , y con un count si me da cero si se podría eliminar la respuesta de la tabla respuestas, también si es null.

Esta es mi tabla de preg_respuestas con los registros:

[image: tABLA PREG_RESPUESTAS]

Y esta es mi tabla de respuestas con los registros:

[image: Tabla respuestas]

Uso php y necesito el query, ya intente de varias maneras el query pero no sale

Comment: No se entiende mucho. ¿Qué es lo que has intentado y que error te da?

Comment: Llevo esto: DELETE FROM respuestas
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM respuestas
) preg_respuestas ON preg_respuestas.id_respuesta= respuestas.id
WHERE preg_respuestas IS NULL
  AND respuestas.id = 3

Comment: Y el error que me sale es que está cerca del left join peor no dice nada más

Comment: Ok, ahora podrías traducir esto: *`Necesito saber cómo puedo hacer un delete ya que una respuesta puede ser usada varias veces en la tabla de preg_respuestas , y con un count si me da cero si se podría eliminar la respuesta de la tabla respuestas, también si es null.`* Es una planteamiento confuso, que no permite entender lo que quieres hacer realmente. ¿Qué quieres borrar, de qué tabla y según qué criterio?

Comment: Quiero borrar la respuesta solo si el valor es null o si no se ha ocupado en la otra tabla que es preg_respuestas, por eso tengo que fijarme en la otra tabla

Comment: Si ves en la captura de la tabla de preg_respuestas hay un id_respuesta este se toma de la tabla de respuestas

Comment: Puedes intentar algo así: `DELETE r FROM respuestas r 
  LEFT JOIN preg_respuestas pr ON pr.id_respuesta = r.id 
      WHERE pr.id_respuesta IS NULL` eso te borrará todas las filas de `respuesta` que no tengan coincidencia en `preg_respuestas`. **Atención**: Haz una copia de seguridad de las tablas antes de intentar cualquier consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido tu query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar algo así:

```
DELETE r FROM respuestas r 
LEFT JOIN preg_respuestas pr ON pr.id_respuesta = r.id 
WHERE pr.id_respuesta IS NULL;
```

Eso te borrará todas las filas de `respuesta` que no tengan coincidencia en `preg_respuestas`, ya que en esos casos, debido al `LEFT JOIN`, la columna `id_respuesta` será `NULL` en aquellas filas que no tengan referencia en `preg_respuestas`

> ## Atención
>
> Haz una copia de seguridad de las tablas antes de intentar cualquier
> consulta.